# UWP Azure Web Apps Auth

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, uwp

I am excited about the latest global (Google, Microsoft, Facebook, etc...) Authentication options in Azure Web Apps. I am posting a Web API app. However does anyone know how to program the login and get a token from a Windows 10 UWP app? I am first interested in using Microsoft Account Authentication.

[image: Azure Global Auth]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to see the excitement!  Some documentation links below.

How to configure Microsoft Account authentication (using the management portal).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication/

Here is some documentation showing how to set up a Windows Store application on Azure App Service. This example uses Facebook, but you should be able to make some very simple changes to enable Microsoft Account authentication.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/

Does this help you get started?

Comment: I have the server side figured out not problem. So the answer is to use the Mobile Services SDK on the client for the authorization?

Comment: Yes, I believe App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Microsoft) is what you would use in your case.

Comment: Will that work without mobile services running on the server?

Comment: @MiddleTommy It should. The new auth stack for mobile apps is built into the App Service platform and works for all app types (web, mobile, api).